# Calculations on multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I would like to calculate the `percent_change()` in prices for each coin subset of data. Applying the below formula returns a value for row 1534 and I would like it to be 0 (as the coin identifier changes):

```
df['prices'].pct_change()
```

I would also like to run other rolling calculation functions on the data, so just replacing the odd value by 0 is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df['pct_chg']=df.groupby([df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()).cumsum(),'coin'])['prices'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
df['pct_chg'] = df['pct_chg'].replace(np.nan, 0)
print(df)
```